# Examples of metrics that are topologically equivalent but have different Cauchy sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm using the following definition for topological equivalence.

Definition: Let $X$ be a set and $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on $X$. Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent if for every $x \in X$, for every $r > 0$, there exists $s = s(r,x)$ such that $B_s^{d_1}(x) \subset B_r^{d_2}(x)$ and $B_s^{d_2}(x) \subset B_r^{d_1}(x)$.

Let $d_1 = |x-y|$ be the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$. I want to find a metric $d_2$ that is topologically equivalent to $d_1$. However, I need a sequence that is Cauchy in $d_1$ but not in $d_2$.

I'm trying to find a simple enough example so that I can prove topological equivalence using the definition. I know we can take $d_2 = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$ and take the sequence $(x_n) = n$, but I can't prove that this $d_2$ is topologically equivalent to $d_1$ using the definition of topological equivalence above. \

So I'm wondering if there is some sort of easier pair of metrics that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Hint: try to find a Cauchy sequence that has no limit... That is, completeness issues...

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to prove that $d_1, d_2$ are topologically equivalent.

The function $\arctan : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, thus for each $x \in \mathbb R$ and each $r > 0$ there exists $s_1 > 0$ such that $\lvert \arctan(y) -  \arctan(x) \lvert < r$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$ with $\lvert y - x \rvert < s_1$. This means $B_{s_1}^{d_1}(x) \subset B_r^{d_2}(x)$.

Similarly, the function $\tan : (-\pi/2,\pi/2) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Thus for for each $\xi \in  (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and each $r > 0$ there exists $s_2 > 0$ such that $\lvert \tan(\eta) -  \tan(\xi) \lvert < r$ for for all $\eta \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with $\lvert \eta - \xi \rvert < s_2$. Thus for each $x \in \mathbb R$ and all $y \in \mathbb R$ with we have $\lvert y - x \rvert = \lvert \tan(\arctan(y)) -  \tan(\arctan(x)) \lvert < r$ for $\lvert \arctan(y) -  \arctan(x) \lvert < s_2$. Thus $B_{s_2}^{d_2}(x) \subset B_r^{d_1}(x)$.

Now take $s = \min(s_1,s_2)$.